# He could be in the market

Tags: modal-verbs

1. A: Where is John?

   B: I don't know. He **could** be in the market.
2. You **could** write a letter to the principal.

The first sentence is a speculation, and the second, a suggestion.

Q: Do we stress the first "could" (speculation) in speech?

Comment: In either sense, the degree of stress placed on _could_ depends on the context. "He **could** be in the market, but I don't think it likely." "You **could** go on foot, but it would be a long way to walk."

Comment: So, stressed "could" is **more uncertain** than unstressed "could". Am I right? Does this apply to "might" as well?

Comment: Yes - stressing the word implies that it is an unlikely possibility, rather than just one of several possibilities. The same applies to _might_.